# Почему не завершается Daemon поток

Tags: python, многопоточность

Я создал программу в которой есть 3 потока: Основной, побочный и побочный от побочного (:D). Другими словами, я пытаюсь создать поток, из которого создаются все другие потоки. Чтобы, убив первый поток, умерли и все остальные потоки. Прочитал про Daemon потоки, что они умирают, когда завершается основной поток или поток, в котором они были запущены. Я так и сделал: создал поток, а из него уже другой, но со свойством Daemon=True. Но при убийстве родительского потока демонический не завершается. С чем это связано?

Comment: Вы что-то неправильное прочитали, daemon-потоки завершаются после того как завершатся все остальные обычные потоки — не только основной или родительский, а вообще все остальные

Comment: А вообще я бы рекомендовал пересмотреть процесс работы программы так, чтобы потоки не убивались, а корректно и аккуратно завершались — так проблем меньше будет

Comment: Всю жизнь "демоны" были системные потоки в юниксах, работающие автономно - почтовый демон и прочие такие.

Comment: @CrazyElf питон любит переворачивать терминологию с ног на голову, в нём и массивы называются списками (:

Answer (score 2):

Главное правило здесь такое: "весь процесс завершается, когда завершается последний не демон поток".

При этом все оставшиеся потоки-демоны завершаются, по сути, аварийно. Идея в том, чтоб не главные потоки не блокировали завершение процесса.

Остановка родительского потока никак не влияет на порожденный им демон (или не демон), разве что косвенно, если это был последний не демон.

Answer (score 1):

Потоки в питоне может завершить только сам поток, нет методов завершить его извне.

В вашем случае надо запустить **процесс**, в котором создадите демонов. Убив процесс демоны завершатся с ним.

Comment: А насколько актуально контролировать дочерние потоки через переменную-переключатель? Ну в дочернем потоке бесконечный цикл, только вместо while True - while Переменная. И менять эту переменную на False, когда надо завершить поток?

Comment: В некоторых случаях. Но обычно в тредах что-то долгое и блокирующее и оперативно дойти до флага не получится.

Comment: В плане что-то долгое и блокирующее? И почему не получится? Не совсем понял комментария, я не очень опытный) Простыми словами, если не сложно, спасибо заранее

Comment: @CSharpLooser зачем вам треды? Что там происходит?

Comment: В одном я в цикле отлавливаю нажатия на клавиши мыши/клавиатуры при помощи w32api, а в другом я симулирую повторяющиеся нажатия клавиш, если пользователь этого потребует. (Например нажимается Ctrl+V, при этом между нажатием/отжатием проходит какое-то рандомное время от 500 до 50 мс и пауза до следующего нажатия от 2000 до 500 мс, я так симулирую "человечность". Ведь у человека нет строгой математической точности, если бы это он нажимал эти клавиши. Там время нажатия и между нажатиями колеблется, а не всегда точно).

Comment: может подойдет.